# Assigning an assignment in C++

Tags: c++

I'm reading a piece of code which does this

```
void *ptr_to_something = (void*)0x23; // I made this up, it's just a pointer to something
void *addr;
void *dst =  (void*)(addr = ptr_to_something); // This is the line that confuses me
```

it seems to assign a pointer to something to another pointer of the same thing. And that's okay.. but then the result is enclosed in parenthesis, cast to the same thing and somehow reassigned to a third pointer to the same thing.

Is this valid C++ at all? Is it guaranteed that assigning the result of an assignment yields the same assigned object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is valid in C++ to do:

```
int a, b, c;

a = b = c = 1;
```

So, therefore the result of an assignment is the value of that assignment.

What the cast is for, is a mystery*.  Have you tried removing it, and does that generate a warning?

*not a mystery, just perhaps unnecessary.

Comment: It's already a void* so just unnecessary. Also note that the assignment operator is on the precidence list and has right-to-left associativity https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 2):

This is valid C++. The choice to format the code this way is odd and not advised, but it's perfectly legal.

This code is equivalent to this (what I consider to be better written) code:

```
void *ptr_to_something = (void*)0x23;
void *addr = ptr_to_something;
void *dst =  addr;
```

Comment: Oh that line was just made up and entirely crap. The address in the real code is calculated elsewhere. Thanks!